# Problems with ssmtp after upgrading to Ubuntu 20.04 LTS - package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 2

Tags: apt, 20.04, upgrade, dpkg, ssmtp

may you can help me i facing this issue since i upgrade to ubuntu 20.04 LTS from 18.04 LTS.
It seems that the script has problems to export value or information.
I have no clue what todo.
Thanks for any help!

Error:

```
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
ssmtp is already the newest version (2.64-8.1ubuntu1).
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
3 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Setting up ssmtp (2.64-8.1ubuntu1) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/ssmtp.config: 11: export: #enables: bad variable name
dpkg: error processing package ssmtp (--configure):
 installed ssmtp package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 2
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of bsd-mailx:
 bsd-mailx depends on default-mta | mail-transport-agent; however:
  Package default-mta is not installed.
  Package postfix which provides default-mta is not installed.
  Package mail-transport-agent is not installed.
  Package ssmtp which provides mail-transport-agent is not configured yet.
  Package postfix which provides mail-transport-agent is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package bsd-mailx (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of apticron:
 apticron depends on bsd-mailx | mailx; however:
  Package bsd-mailx is not configured yet.
  Package mailx is not installed.
  Package bsd-mailx which provides mailx is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package apticron (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                                                                                                                                    Errors were encountered while processing:
 ssmtp
 bsd-mailx
 apticron
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)´´´
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the output of /var/lib/dpkg/info/ssmtp.config:

> #!/bin/sh
> set -e
>
> . /usr/share/debconf/confmodule
>
> if [ -f /etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf ]
> then
> for v in `grep -E >"^(root|mailhub|rewriteDomain|hostname|FromLineOverride)=" /etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf`
> do
> export $v
> done
>
> ```
>   db_set ssmtp/root "$root"
>   if [ -n "$mailhub" ]
>   then
>           if [ `expr index "$mailhub" :` -ne 0 ]
>           then
>                   db_set ssmtp/port "${mailhub#*:}"
>                   db_set ssmtp/mailhub "${mailhub%:*}"
>           else
>                   db_set ssmtp/port 25
>                   db_set ssmtp/mailhub "$mailhub"
>           fi
>    fi
>   if [ -n "$rewriteDomain" ]
>   then
>           db_set ssmtp/rewritedomain "$rewriteDomain"
>   fi
>   if [ -n "$hostname" ]
>   then
>           db_set ssmtp/hostname "$hostname"
>   fi
>   if [ -n "$FromLineOverride" ]
>   then
>           if [ "$FromLineOverride" = "YES" ]
>           then
>                   db_set ssmtp/fromoverride true
>           else
>                   db_set ssmtp/fromoverride false
>           fi
>   fi
> ```
>
> fi
>
> db_input medium ssmtp/root || true
> db_go
>
> db_input medium ssmtp/mailhub || true
> db_go
>
> db_input low ssmtp/port || true
> db_go
>
> db_input medium ssmtp/rewritedomain || true
> db_go
>
> db_input low ssmtp/hostname || true
> db_go
>
> db_input medium ssmtp/fromoverride || true
> db_go
>
> ## Program End
>
> exit 0

Answer (score 0):

I could solve the problem by checking the ssmtp.config file under /etc/ssmtp/

There is a line with the FromLineOverride=YES parameter followed by a comment.
This comment seems to be the problem. When i moved the comment a line up so that only the parameter i in a line the problem is solved.